# Accessing Arrays in Dictionaries (swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I can't seem to find a solution for how to type out the syntax. I want to access and be able to modify individual integers within an array that's nested in a larger dictionary.

Here's an example:

```
var exampleDictionary = [ 1: [2,3] , 2: [4,5] , 3: [7,8] ]

print (exampleDictionary[2]!)   // prints [4,5]
```

How can I access the **first value** of **Key 2** *(4 above)*?

How can I change just the **first value** of **Key 2**?

I'm trying things like this and it's not working:

```
exampleDictionary[2[0]] = (exampleDictionary[2[0]] - 3) // want to change [4,5] to [1,5]
print (exampleDictionary[2[0]])  // should print "1"

exampleDictionary[2 : [0]] = (exampleDictionary[2 :[0]] - 3)
print (exampleDictionary[2 : [0]])
```

Comment: Replace the old array with the new one, `exampleDictionary[2] = [1,5]`

Answer (score 4):

You should subscript the array not its index :

```
exampleDictionary[2]![0] = (exampleDictionary[2]?[0] ?? 0) - 3
```

Safer would be to use optional binding like so:

```
if var array = exampleDictionary[2] {
    array[0] -= 3
    exampleDictionary[2] = array
}
```

Comment: This worked - Thank you! What is the  "?? 0" for in the 2nd half of the equation?

Comment: @gg1789 that is the nil-coalescing operator, you can read more about it here https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID72

Answer (score 0):

You have always to consider that Swift collection types are value types and you have to modify the object *in place*, something like

```
if let firstValueOfKey2 = exampleDictionary[2]?.first {
    print(firstValueOfKey2)
    exampleDictionary[2]!.first = firstValueOfKey2 - 3
    print(exampleDictionary[2]!.first!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have dictionary of type `[Int: [Int]]`, which means every key have a value of array from `Int`.

1.If your `exampleDictionary` is of unrelated type, Specify the type of `exampleDictionary` to `[Int: [Int]]` so that you won't need to cast it in next step.

```
var exampleDictionary: [Int: [Int]] = [ 1: [2,3] , 2: [4,5] , 3: [7,8] ]
```

2.Access the key you want.

```
var key2: [Int] = exampleDictionary[2]!

var firstValueOfKey2: Int = key2.first!
```

3.Change the value for key2:

```
key2 = [1,5]
```

4.Because of Swift, `Collections` are value type which means that a pointer refers to new block in memory, this means that you cant change the value from root object directly from modifiers. then you should assign the last result to root object.

```
exampleDictionary[2] = key2
```